# Assign value to Eloquent model after mass-asignment in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have the following code:

```
public function postCreate($subjectId = null) {
    if ($subjectId) {
        $subject = Subject::find($subjectId);

        $input = Input::all();

        $v = Validator::make($input, Product::$rules);

        if ($v->passes()) {
            $product = new Product($input);
            $amazon_product = new AmazonProduct($input['amazon_id']);
            $product->price($amazon_product->price());

            $subject->products()->save($product);

            Session::flash('message', 'Produkt erfolgreich gespeichert');
            return Redirect::to('boss/subjects/show/'.$subjectId);
        }
    } else {
        Session::flash('message', 'Innerhalb der POST-Action muss die Gruppen-ID angegeben sein.');
        return Redirect::to('boss/subjects');
    }
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::price()
```

I think the problem is the mass-asignment happening at `$product = new Product($input);`

Is there any way to assign another value AFTER that? The value for `price` is not present within `$product`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use this:

```
$product->price = $amazon_product->price();
```

Instead of:

```
$product->price($amazon_product->price());
```

Here, `$product` is the `Eloquent Model` object and `price` is a property of that object but you are using it as a `method`.

Comment: Of course, what a stupid mistake. Was too late yesterday :) Thank you!